# Which question should be answered for almost duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

#### Context

This question comes from this one: *[How to join two table in pandas based on time with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982636/how-to-join-two-table-in-pandas-based-on-time-with-delay)*. It is almost a duplicate of [Merging two dataframes based on a date between two other dates without a common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593554/merging-two-dataframes-based-on-a-date-between-two-other-dates-without-a-common), except that the answer on the duplicate only works with small data frames, while this one wants to use larger data frames.

I first read the other question, and then its accepted answer and came to the conclusion that the answer could not apply to that case. As I had already handled a close problem I decided to post an answer.

#### Problem

I then realized that my answer could be adapted to the original question, even if it is currently specifically focused on the other question. And began to wonder which one I should have answered

#### Question

Was I right in answering the new question because the accepted answer on the proposed duplicate could not apply, or should I have VTCed the new question and posted a new answer (despite the existence of an accepted and upvoted one) on the old one?

Comment: "'Almost' only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades."  No sense in trying to shoehorn a dupe if one doesn't cleanly exist.

Comment: (Also I'd answer *this* Meta question, but since I don't know Pandas I feel underqualified to evaluate it.)

Answer (score 2):

As [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) says [in the comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380880/which-question-should-be-answered-for-almost-duplicates#comment674842_380880):

> Almost only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades

A question is only a duplicate of a target question if all possible solutions to the target problem are also possible solutions to the original problem and vice versa. If you've determined that solution(s) at the target question do not apply to the original, it is not a duplicate.

It's OK if the same solution solves multiple problems. Just make sure that you tailor the solution and explanation to the specific question such that it makes the most sense in context. If someone is asking how to merge two small dataframes and you start of by saying "To merge two massive dataframes..." as if they had asked for that, it won't make much sense to the reader.

I have no experience with the target technology so I will defer to your judgement on whether or not the solutions are mutually applicable.